# SQL query - testing the absence of a person name

Tags: sql

How can I test if a content of a field is in my table? For example the name "Anne".
I'd like to write a condition that says "if this name is not in my table" then...

Thanks

Comment: Where is this condition placed? Inside a query or inside a trigger, store procedure, function...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE [Name] = 'Anne')
BEGIN
   ....
END
```

`NOT EXISTS` is preferable to `COUNT(*) = 0`. The latter form sometimes requires a suitable index to perform well (i.e. not perform a full table scan; depending on the available indexes).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you're trying to do it as a procedure or a simple SQL query/update. Mitch has given a good solution for the former. If it's the latter, the following is a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT ... FROM MyTable
WHERE  NOT NameColumn = 'Anne'
AND ...
```

You could also check for partials by replacing `=` with `LIKE` as such:

```
WHERE NOT NameColumn LIKE 'Anne%'
```

or

```
WHERE NOT NameColumn LIKE '%Anne%'
```

But bear in mind that `LIKE` has performance considerations depending on the size of your table, and other factors.